# Подсчет количества цифр в каждом из целочисленных элементов массива

Tags: java, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подсчитать количество цифр в каждом из целочисленных элементов массива `int`. Скажем, массив выглядит так:

```java
int array[] = new int[]{28, 38, 72024, 8000};
```

Comment: перевести в строку например и взять `length`........ а можно на 10 рекурсивно делить (со счётчиком) пока у числа целая часть не закончится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это понятно, как сделать для каждого из элементов. Например, для того, чтобы просто выводил в консоль.

Comment: делать цикл по массиву, а внутри по вышеуказанному алгоритму

Comment: можно, но это алгоритм не оптимальный. на много быстрее в цикле число делить на 10 и считать количество итераций. для 4 чисел разницы, разумеется, никакой, но для большого количества будет ощутима

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович интересно, вы назвали алгоритм не оптимальный а потом описали его же...хм...

Comment: @АндрейГлазков так счетчик обнулять надо на каждой новой цифре

Comment: @АлексейШиманский понял, спасибо!

Comment: я говорил о том, что перевод в строку не оптимальный. думал понятна будет идея...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так, используя Stream API:

```
IntStream.of(array)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Сначала создаем из массива поток, преобразуем каждый элемент в строку, берем длину каждой строки и выводим.

Answer (score 0):

Можно посчитать сколько тысяч, десятков, сотен. Потом сложить их для каждого элемента массива:

```
int input = 123;
int units = input % 10;// единицы
int n = input / 10;
int tens = n % 10;// десятки
n = n / 10;
int hundreds = n % 10;// сотни
n = n / 10;
int thousands = n % 10;// тысячи
int result = units + tens + hundreds + thousands;
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Comment: У вас будет в цикле input = array[i];

Answer (score 0):

Можно из массива собрать карту - из скольких цифр состоит каждое число:

```java
int[] arr = {28, 38, 72024, 8000};

Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.summingInt(i -> String.valueOf(i).length())));

System.out.println(map); // {28=2, 38=2, 72024=5, 8000=4}
```